Server Action vs API in next.js
I've been looking more into Next and creating projects but confused as to what the pros and cons are for creating either a server action or an api for things like creating a user and saving to database or for updating user details within a database. I've seen a lot of mixed things so I'm not sure as to which would be better

Unlike API Routes, Server Actions are a higher-level abstraction. They are a simpler way to write server-side code and can be called from the client-side as POST requests. They are particularly useful when you want to perform actions/mutations on the server-side, such as creating a new user, or updating a user's profile:
export default async function MyUser(props: Props) {
  const { id } = props.params;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id } });

  // seemless integration into your server component
  const updateUser = async (data: Partial<User>) => {
    "use server";
    try {
      const result = await prisma.user.update({ where: { id }, data });
      return result;
    } catch {
      return null;
    }
  };

  // a client component that uses the updateUser function
  return <UserProfile initialData={user} onUpdate={updateUser} />;
}

Thanks to utilities such as revalidatePath and revalidateTag, you can also use Server Actions to invalidate the cache of a specific page or tag (used with fetch).
